# Decoupling template location from views

Tags: django, django-views

Probably a simple question, as I only have started with Django.

I have followed the famous Django tutorial and decoupling views from project is rather obvious:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^testpath/', include('test_app.urls')),
)
```

and test_app urls are mapped to "path/"

Now, in the views I would like to avoid hardcoding of the path (example from the tutorial):

```
def index(request):
   latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
   context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
   return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

where `polls/` is a hard coded path to an app. I believe there must be a way, so an application can be used in different application without changing the code.

EDIT:

The project templates directory:

```
/templates
  index.html
  /polls
    index.html
```

I would like to get a template from `/templates/polls/index.html` without hardcoding `polls` into a view. So in the next project I can have for example:

```
/templates
  index.html
  /random_polls
    index.html
```

(I am aware of `app_directories.Loader`, but that means using templates within an app, which is not ideal in my mind)

Answer (score 0):

Django will try to find complete path for the template. So specifying `'polls/index.html'` or just `'index.html'` is same. You will have to make sure that templates are appropriately available in template directories with the specified path.

You can specify template directories through [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_DIRS) in settings.

Finding template dirs also depends upon [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS) setting as well.

More details at [Loading templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates)

Comment: That's the problem - Django disregards urls mapping when getting templates. I would like it to try to hit "polls/index.html" before "index.html".

Comment: @Juliusz, You can put `/templates/polls` directory before `/templates`  in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. It will be loaded in that order. But then always `/templates/polls/index.html` will be served when `index.html` is used in any views.